# What is getInitialProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I think it might be a stupid question to ask but trust me I am new to Next.js and I am trying to fully understand how the `getInitialProps` lifecycle hook works. I did some queries but still I am not able to use it effectively. What I have understood is that `getInitialProps` is used to fetch data on server but, I am still confused on how we can do it on the server if we already have an `http` lib like `axios` etc. 
Could someone please help to answer my question. Why do we need `getInitialProp` in Next.js?

Comment: A similar question has been answered in this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136824/nextjs-getinitialprops-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your might use axios or whatever else to make your http calls, the important thing is **where you're making the http call, on the server? or on the user's browser?**

If you put the fetch code on the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook, it's always going to run on the browser, if you put it in the `getInitialProps()` it's going to run on the server.

*[The above statement is only valid when you're trying to open the page for the first time, after that everything will happen on the browser regardless of where you've put the fetch code, More info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#server-side-rendering)]*

---

### Comparison

What nextjs does, is that it runs your React app on a server before handing it over to the user's browser. By doing so, it returns a fully rendered HTML, with the content fully loaded.

**With normal React app:**

1. Your browser requests for index.html
2. React app gets loaded in your browser and calls `componentDidMount()`
3. Data is fetched and the state is changed accordingly
4. React renders the fetched content on your browser

**With Next.js:**

1. Your browser requests for index.html
2. Nextjs grabs your React app and calls `getInitialProps`
3. Data is fetched and the props will get passed to your component
4. React renders the fetched content for Next.js
5. Nextjs sends the rendered HTML to your browser